# Anyone point me towards a nice thumbnails image picker?

Tags: jquery, overlay, thumbnails

I have a div which contains images. When they are clicked they fill table cells. I am looking for a something which I can use to pop-up/overlay this selection of thumbnails. Can a div be used as an image picker? I've seen plenty of gallery type ones but none for just thumbnail size. Any ideas welcome. P.S. Is it hard to create one of these? I'm under a bit of time pressure on it. Thanks.

Comment: So you want your div of images to be a dialog which overlays the rest of the site?

Comment: Hi yes I need to be able to click the image, the overlay disappears and the new image replaces the placeholder image. I have this working with a div containing test images that appends, but I want to style it as a full screen overlay, if that's the correct word

Comment: Ok, then add a class to it so you can style it with CSS. The overlay will come from the styling. The behavior of showing/hidding the div will come from Javascript.

Comment: Sounds good. The div already shows onclick of table cell/placeholder image and hides when an image is picked. So you're saying I just need to style the div then? Oooops just saw your addition. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. I presume it won't affect my click functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a class to the `div` that you want to turn into a dialog (modal, overlay, etc). Then add the appropriate CSS to position as desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/cwjtQ/

Here is some example CSS to position a window in the center of the browser window:

```
.dialog {
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -250px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```